# How do I prevent ASP.NET from converting the & symbol to &amp; when adding a url to a control's attributes?

Tags: asp.net, attributes, url

This is what I'm adding and it renders the `&` as `&amp;`

sharelink.Attributes.Add("addthis:url", "http://" & Request.Url.Host & "/Resources/PublicView.aspx?RID=" & R.ResourceID & "&Key=" & Key)

I need it to render this

```
?RID=64&Key=%2fwEUKwEDAgQCFAJA
```

instead of this

```
?RID=64&amp;Key=%2fwEUKwEDAgQCFAJA
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to.  Did you try it?

Comment: I did try it.  still this doesn't answer the question of why when I tell .net to output one string that I get another.  You may be right that some borwsers or servres can accomodate the &amp; but that still leaves the question as to why it was changed in the first place.

Comment: Microsoft's dev team, knows &amp ; should be used, that why they... ! Wait a minute! Internet Explorer (6, 7, 8?) isn't supporting &amp ; in iframes' sources attributes. I guess being able to use & instead of & should have come to their mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting to `&amp;` is correct, and the browsers should be able to handle it.

[Source](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html?a=b&c=d#amp)

To prove it, look at the source for [this hyperlink](http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html?a=b&c=d#amp).

**EDIT**: To explain, this is the *correct* way to do it.  Writing `<a href="a.com?b=c&d=e">` is **wrong**.  Just like ASP.Net will use entities if you write `<asp:Label runat="server" Text="><><" />`, it will also use entities if you put an ampersand in an attribute.

Comment: that isn't true when you are trying to break up the values in a query string.  & is a reserved character used to seperate the key value pairs.

Comment: The browser should decode the `&amp;` and send `&` in the URL.

Comment: "To avoid problems with both validators and browsers, always use &amp; in place of & when writing URLs in HTML:"  This isn't a problem with writting a url but with seperating the query string parameters.  are you suggesting that if I have a string abc.com?a=1&amp;b=2&amp;c=3 that this will be parsed to be a=1, b=2 and c=3 ?

Comment: Yes.  The browser will decode the `&amp;` when parsing the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I post this comment as an answer due to limitation in commenting.

I agree with the [answer by SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114401/how-do-i-prevent-asp-net-from-converting-the-symbol-to-amp-when-adding-a-url/2114407#2114407), this is especially so for strict XHTML compliance.

I've created a demo page with both `&` and `&amp;` which can be used for W3C validation.

See the demo page at http://74er.net/labs/amp-or-not.html and click on the bottom-most hyperlink to perform a w3c validation, or [click here to validate directly](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F74er.net%2Flabs%2Famp-or-not.html).

The errors will be highlighted, all targetted at the line 14:

```
href="http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&ie=UTF-8"
```

Whereas a similar one at line 19 with `&amp;` will pass:

```
href="http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&amp;ie=UTF-8"
```